# How to select date future in datepicker jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i'm using `datePicker` in this way:

```
$("#dataStart").datepicker({
beforeShow: function () { $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index',9999); },
dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'});
$("#dataEnd").datepicker({
beforeShow: function () { $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index',9999); },
dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'});
```

I want to force select a date in future and not in the past, is there a possibility to do it?
if so, is possible to change in a dynamic way for the second datepicker, so if user select a date, in the second field he has to select a date next to the first selected.
i hope i ask as well my question :)
Thanks all!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`minDate:1` should only allow dates tomorrow and onward.  Then add an `onselect` to restrict `dataEnd`:

```
$("#dataStart").datepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    onSelect: function(theDate) {
        $("#dataEnd").datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(theDate));
    },
    beforeShow: function() {
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index', 9999);
    },
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
});
```

Reference: http://blog.alagad.com/2009/04/20/playing-with-jquery-datepicker/

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/F39kt/

Answer (score 2):

If you return [false] in `beforeShowDay` event of datepicker it disables that day. You can compare the date and the current date and return [true/false] accordingly.

Try this.

```
$("#dataStart").datepicker({
     beforeShow: function () { 
         $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index',9999); 
     },
     dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
});
$("#dataEnd").datepicker({
     beforeShow: function () { 
         $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index',9999); 
     },
     dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
     beforeShowDay: function(date){
          return [(date > ($("#dataStart").datepicker("getDate") 
                          || new Date()))];
     }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qnHBz/2/)**

Comment: @JackTurky - Added the code to compare the End date with Start date and disable the dates accordingly. If the Start date is not available I am simply comparing it with current date.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+10);
var prettyDate =(myDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + myDate.getDate() + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();

$("#thedate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',altFormat: 'yyyymmdd'});
$("#thedate").val(prettyDate);
```

This is how I do it. 'thedate' is my datepicker. I'm bumping the date to today + 10 days.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var dates=$("#from, #to").datepicker({
     changeMonth:true, onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
         var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
         instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
         date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings );
         dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/.

Look at the `minDate` option. You can set it dynamically with the `option` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but it's somewhat unclarified. Could be because of changes to the jQuery UI Widget itself, but for anyone stumbling upon this:

To limit datepickers scope to future dates only - set the `minDate` param to 0.

To limit to past dates only you would set the `maxDate` param to 0.

This is nice because it avoids having to call a `new Date()` function as is suggested elsewhere in this thread.

Example:

```
$('.your_datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: 0
});
```